# Convert sheet (ideally range) to picture

Tags: java, image, apache-poi, aspose-cells

is there a way to convert a range of a POI sheet to image (any extension) ?
Is there an library that can help me do that (beside aspose) ?

Thank you so much

Comment: A sheet is a collection of data, how it is presented totally depends on the application being used. As such it is possible to "render" a sheet or a range of it into an image but it might get a bit complex. Depending on what you need you could try generating html out of the data and render that (I'd bet there are [some libs](https://code.google.com/archive/p/java-html2image/) for that).

Comment: @Thomas Thank you for you answer, I've seen some tips to convert to HTML than convert to image.
But my question before going this way is : Does the render to html will change the overall look (i want to keep the same look)

Comment: Of course the look will be different, i.e. it will be what you define it to be. As I said how a spreadsheet will be displayed highly depends on the application being used to display it (the same sheet will look differently in MS Office, Libre Office, Google Docs etc.). Thus you'll need to define the look of your html but of course you can define it in a way that comes close to the application you want to mimick (although that might be quite some complex task).

Answer (score 0):

[Aspose.Cells](https://www.aspose.com/products/cells/net) can convert your Range into Image. Please see the following article for sample code. The code first sets the print area to your desired range. For example, in the article, it is setting **print area** to **E18:H15**. You can also set print area manually with Microsoft Excel. After setting print area, it takes the image of entire worksheet using the `options.OnePagePerSheet = true` statement. But entire worksheet will not be printed in the image and only the range E18:H15 will be printed in the image, hence your purpose is achieved.

**Please note**, if you do not set the print area and **OnePagePerSheet** is true, then you will get the image of entire worksheet. And if OnePagePerSheet is false, then you will get as number of images as there are number of pages inside the worksheet.

**Article Link:**
[Export Range of Cells in a Worksheet to Image](https://docs.aspose.com//display/cellsnet/Export+Range+of+Cells+in+a+Worksheet+to+Image)

***Note:*** I am working as Developer Evangelist at Aspose

Comment: Thanks, but it's not free, I need something free